# D-optimal DOE suggest repeated samples

Tags: experiment-design, geometry, constraint, convex, optimal

I tried to generate a D optimal design but the design output sounds very weird to me. I have a (real) process and I`d like to explore 3 factors, but the process have a lot of constraints so I provide a candidate set for the design generator. I have 20 possibilities, but only have money/time for 12 samples.

Let me paste the code here (I'm using `gen_design` function, from `skpr` package at R language)

```r
config_machine <- matrix(c(5, 3, 20, 
    5, 3, 2210.,
    5, 1, 1753.,
    4, 3, 2105.,
    4, 1, 2022.,
    4, 1, 874,
    5, 3, 2001.,
    4, 3, 979,
    5, 3, 811,
    5, 2, 750,
    4, 1, 853,
    4, 2, 1836.,
    4, 3, 895,
    5, 3, 100,
    5, 2, 832,
    4, 2, 2043.,
    4, 3, 1795.,
    4, 1, 1815.,
    4, 2, 937,
    4, 3, 1920.),3,20)
config_machine <- t(config_machine)
colnames(config_machine) <- c('X1', 'X2', 'X3')
df <- as.data.frame(config_machine)
design <- gen_design(candidateset = df, model = ~X1 + X2 + X3, 
    trials = 12,repeats = 1000)
design
```

But the optimal design will show some like this

```r
row X1 X2 X3
1 5 3 20
2 5 3 2210
3 5 3 20
4 4 3 2105
5 5 1 1753
6 5 1 1753
7 5 3 2210
8 4 3 2105
9 4 1 853
10 4 3 2105
11 5 3 20
12 4 1 853
```

Sounds very weird to me the sample 1,3 and 11 are the same point (5,3,20)! I only have 12 samples but the function is wasting my samples using repeated measures. What is my mistake? I tried to read the documentation but didn`t find any tip.

Minutes ago I tried to solve the same design at minitab, but the output design was also show repeated samples.
Any tips?

---

Actually the factor X1 and X2 are categorical, and I need provide this information for gen_design. This was my mistake :).

Just for curiosity I`ll share more information about my process.

- X1 are a type of engine, the amount of blades at engine (categorical)
- X2 are a manufacturer (categorical)
- X3 is the relative distance from the first engine at the factory

We have 50 machines at total but we only have budget to install sensors at 12 machines. We`ll use information from this 12 sensors to provide some kind of machine behavior of the other 38 machines.
We are developing a R&D project for intend to increase efficiency from the total 50 engines.

We think that use D-optimal DOE sounds a good idea to choose the 12 machines.

Comment: To the downvoters: This question is on-topic and clear enough!

Comment: X1 sounds like a cont variable, not then categorical (8 blades is more than 5 blades, so should be treated as numerical. X2 categorical, X3 numerical.  Why do you believe that `relative distance from first engine` is an important variable? (not clear what it is)

Comment: Jketil, actually we have this machines inside a river and the enviroment conditions should be diferent between the first machine, the machine at middle and the last machine (water speed, water quality, turbulence).

Answer (score 1):

After running your code I did

```r
lapply(df,  range)
$X1
[1] 4 5

$X2
[1] 1 3

$X3
[1]   20 2210
```

and comparing with the generated `design`, observe that for `X1` only the extremes 4 and 5 are used, same for `X2`, while `X3` has some interior points. That make me actually doubt you found an actual optimum!  What happens is: For a D-optimal design for the simple model `~ X1`, an optimal design will be concentrated on the minimum and maximum points of the range of `X1`. This should not be too difficult to prove. The idea is that the optimization assumes (as it must), that the model is correct, and does not assign some points to check for linearity, say. So if you want a design that have some interior points, try the model `~ x1 + I(X1^2)`. It is not clear how this generalizes to a linear model with multiple variables, if an orthogonal design is possible, that could be preferred (and will omit interior points), but if not possible, maybe the inclusion of some interior points could make correlations closer to zero, which could improve the determinant. But as a general rule, D-optimal designs will prefer boundary points (think that a determinant is a hyper-volume, and to increase volume you should go to the boundary.)

But *going to the boundary* suggests finding the convex hull of the points in `df`. We should expect the points actually used in the design should be taken from the corner points on the convex hull (which in this case will be the smallest polyhedron enclosing all the points.) We can do that by

```r
     hulldf <- geometry::convhulln(df)
     hulldf
          [,1] [,2] [,3]
     [1,]   13   11    1
     [2,]    5   11    3
     [3,]    5    2    4
     [4,]    5    2    3
     [5,]   10   11    1
     [6,]   10   11    3
     [7,]   13    2    1
     [8,]   13    2    4
     [9,]    5   13    4
    [10,]    5   13   11
    [11,]   10    2    1
    [12,]   10    2    3
    attr(,"convhulln")
    <pointer: 0x55e02aa9e120>
    > unique(c(hulldf))
    [1] 13  5 10 11  2  1  3  4
```

The last line above gives the row numbers from `df` of the points forming the convex hull. We should expect the optimal design to be chosen from this points.  To find the points actually used in `design`, do

```r
    findrows <- function(df1,  df2) {
        stopifnot(NCOL(df1)==NCOL(df2))
        # For each row in df2,  find which row it equals in df1
        N <- NROW(df2)
        out <- integer(length=N)
        for (i in 1:N) {
            row <- c(df2[i, ])
            for (j in 1:(NROW(df1))) {
                  if(isTRUE(all.equal(row, c(df1[j, ])))) 
    {out[i]<-j; break}
                }
        }
        out
    }
    
    used <- findrows(df, design)
     used
     [1]  3  1  4  1  2  3 11  4  4  1  2 11
     table(used)
    used
     1  2  3  4 11 
     3  2  2  3  2 
     unique(used)
    [1]  3  1  4  2 11
```

and by comparing with the output above we find that the rows 5, 10, 13 which are corners on the convex hull was not used in the design. That merits an investigation into why.

You could try

```r
    design2 <- gen_design(candidateset = df, model = ~ X1 + X2 + 
                 X3 + X1:X2 + X1:X3 + X2:X3 + I(X2^2) + I(X3^2), 
                 trials = 12,repeats = 1000)
    
      design2
       X1 X2   X3
    1   5  2  750
    2   4  2 2043
    3   5  3   20
    4   4  1 2022
    5   5  3 2210
    6   4  1  853
    7   4  3  895
    8   4  3 2105
    9   5  1 1753
    10  4  2  937
    11  5  3  811
    12  5  3   20
```

and compare. We did not include `I(X1^2)` because the variable `X1` does only have two levels.  If what you want is a response surface design, that could be better. But you didn't tell us your ultimate goal with the design.

Comment: Thanks kjetil! I`ll read your response more times to try to understand your comment in deep. Thanks for help!

Comment: If you like it you can upvote (and accept) it!

Comment: Kjetil, I tried to upvote your answer but I don`t have enough points to do that. I`m beginner and don`t have 15 point to stackexchange allow me upvote your answer. I find my mistake (I believe...) and I`ll write about that

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen can you please look into [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457377/d-optimal-criteria-vs-differential-shannon-entropy) and see if you could contribute there as well.